# Internet drops out when I connect my Raspi to netowrk

Tags: networking, pi-4, internet

After setting up my Raspberry Pi to act as a NAS things worked well for a few days however today whenever the device is connected via Ethernet to my router the internet cuts out for all devices connected to the network. What is causing this issue? - Do I need to buy a new PI or perhaps a dedicated NAS solution to stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your router?

Comment: It should be possible to use a Pi as a NAS. I have been using a Pi4 and a 2 TB USB-3 drive as a NAS with Samba for the last 2 years. Have you tried a fresh Raspbian image?

Comment: Have you got several squillion torrents going?

Comment: Possibly an IP address conflict, are you using a static IP for your NAS ?